# Read nested JSON object

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I want to read nested JSON and store the data in database. I get JSON object as "application/json" from post method to my WCF Service.

For this I am converting the JSON to Dictionary. But getting first level values only. Getting object for second level JSON.

Below is the code I am using to covert JSON to Dictionary:

```
[Serializable]
public class JsonDictionary : ISerializable
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> m_entries;

    public JsonDictionary()
    {
        m_entries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Entries
    {
        get { return m_entries; }
    }

    protected JsonDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        m_entries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var entry in info)
        {
            m_entries.Add(entry.Name, entry.Value);
        }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var entry in m_entries)
        {
            info.AddValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the JSON posting to the WCF:

In this, getting object instead of value for "office_address", "financial_details","residence_address" and "personal_details".

```js
{
    "business_name": "Test Business",
    "fk_loan_id": "kh-aaaaa3232",
    "proprietor_details": {
        "office_address": {
            "email_id": "aaa.aaa@aaa.com",
            "alternative_mobile_number": "00000",
            "pincode": "00000",
            "landline_number": "00000",
            "city": "Tutne",
            "flat_number": "000",
            "street": "Test Street",
            "locality": "tLocality",
            "state": "SGDS",
            "mobile_number": "0000000000"
        },
        "date_of_incorporation": "01/03/2010",
        "financial_details": {
            "TAN": "ghdg45341f",
            "TIN": "dc5345fg6g",
            "VAT": "dgdgd544t4",
            "PAN": "AAAAA7614A"
        },
        "residence_address": {
            "email_id": "aaa.-aa@aa.com",
            "alternative_mobile_number": "0000000",
            "pincode": "00000",
            "landline_number": "00000",
            "city": "SFSS",
            "flat_number": "055",
            "street": "DASAW",
            "locality": "Local",
            "state": "AAAAA",
            "mobile_number": "000000"
        },
        "personal_details": {
            "gender": "M",
            "date_of_birth": "06/07/1969",
            "last_name": "AAA",
            "middle_name": "A",
            "first_name": "AAAA"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've defined your dictionary as `Dictionary<string, object>` and you're getting an `object` for a key. That's what a `Dictionary<string, object>` does. If you want it to return something other than an object, don't use `object` as your value type.

Comment: Anything I use, it consider's office_address as object whose count is 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this -
`var innerProperties =  yourObject.proprietor_details;`

This will give you the properties inside proprietor_details.

i created a mvc web api  here is the code

```
namespace TestWebApi.Controllers
{
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post(ComplexClass data)
    {
        var xx = data.business_name;
        var y = xx + data.date_of_incorporation;
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ComplexClass
{
    public string business_name { get; set; }
    public string fk_loan_id { get; set; }
    public proprietor_details proprietor_details {get;set;}
    public string date_of_incorporation { get; set; }
    public financial_details financial_details { get; set; }
    public residence_address residence_address {get;set;}
    public personal_details personal_details {get;set;}
}

public  class financial_details
{
  public string TAN { get; set; }
  public string TIN { get; set; }
  public string VAT { get; set; }
  public string  PAN { get; set; }
  }
```

make other classes also ...

here is the json data for post call i am using 
     {
        "business_name": "Test Business",
    "fk_loan_id": "kh-aaaaa3232",
    "proprietor_details": null,
        "date_of_incorporation": "01/03/2010",
          "financial_details": {
            "TAN": "ghdg45341f",
            "TIN": "dc5345fg6g",
            "VAT": "dgdgd544t4",
            "PAN": "AAAAA7614A"
        },
        "residence_address": null,
        "personal_details": null
    }
        attaching image for fiddler call
[image]

attaching data tree image
[[image: ][1]]

Comment: Hi, i am using below method to read created dictionary:                  public Main ApplyNewLoan(ApplyNewLoan applyloan)
    {      
        var innerProperties = applyloan.proprietor_details;
        return db.ApplyLoan(applyloan);
    }
But with this i can read upto proprietor_details, as jSonDictionary. I need to read "office_address" as well. But it is reading it as an object.

Comment: Then you should try yourObject.proprietor_details.office_address

Comment: I created an api for the same for test. I am getting proper propeties from the json data in my web api.

Comment: Hi, m stuck in jSon string again.

Comment: "loan_application_documents": {"entity_documents_details_list": [
      {"entity_type": "test entity",
        "documents": [{ "metadata_list": [{ "document_name": "test1 doc",
                                    "file_extension": ".doc", "document_url": "www.google.com" } ], "document_id": "doc123", "document_type": "test type" }], "entity_id": "ent123"}]}                                                                                                           I can read all the values, except "document_name","file_extension","document_url".Getting null as values for these. Kindly help.